# Android Render and Physics on separate threads?

Tags: android, multithreading, surfaceview, physics

I recently had problem getting my physics to stop racing ahead of my rendering (they were on the same thread), After a few months, I resolved the problem in about 20 minutes by creating a new thread and putting by physics into that.

I find that having them completely separate from each other gives me far greater control and now my sprites are moving consistently across all screens at all frame rates.

My question is, is it 'better' to put logic and rendering in the same thread or separate threads?  The latter seems better to me but does it cause any problems? (does if affect battery life for example?)

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah it is definitely better to use multiple threads, especially if the calculation is non-trivial, in which case you could experience the dreaded "Activity Not Responding" dialog.

Something that I would definitely look into would be `AsyncTasks` http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html . Essentially, you would perform all of your physics calculation in the `doInBackground` method(which is running in a background thread) and then periodically call `publishProgress` from within that(which will execute the 'onProgressUpdate' callback where you will do all of your rendering on the UI thread).

Comment: Yep I will definately look into Asnyc Task - one thing I don't understand though is that when I have these on separate threads, although the speed is much more consistent, the sprites are a little bit more 'choppy' - I am assuming this is because the rendering might be happening before the logic has finished updating, is there any way around this?

Comment: Hmm, I couldn't really say for sure why the rendering would be more choppy. How are you communicating between your background thread and the UI thread?

Comment: All I've done so far is create a new thread, put all my logic into it and started the thread along with the rendering thread in my surfaceCreated() method - nothing more as yet!

Comment: So you spawn 1 thread or 2 threads in your surfaceCreated() callback? Is your rendering thread the same as your main(UI) thread? Also, when you say you just threw the logic into a separte thread, does this mean that your communication mechanism between the 2 threads is shared, global variables? If so, that could be the cause of the choppiness.

Comment: I'm using surfaceView which as I understand it, uses a separate thread for rendering (separate from the UI thread) - so I have 3 threads.  You are correct, all of my variables are global - could you advise why this may cause an issue?  Thanks!

Comment: If your background thread is the only producer, there shouldn't be any sort of race condition issues, but if you have multiple producers there may be some race condtions. I am not sure how your consumer threads are being notified of newly written data, but if they are polling it, there could be some lag time between the time it's written to by the producer and read by the consumer thread.

Answer (score 0):

Actually using different threads for performing logic and rendering UI is really and always appreciated.and it correct also.

But to handle/manage the multiple thread is the harder responsibility for a programmer.

And as the threads also increase the battery consumption, so we should always use thread very carefully.

So the final outcome is use threads but carefully. because thread are useful is used optimally but dangerous is not used carefully.

Answer (score 0):

You said...
"I'm using surfaceView which as I understand it, uses a separate thread for rendering (separate from the UI thread) - so I have 3 threads"

It sounds like you're assuming that by extending SurfaceView, you're automatically provided with another underlying thread for the Surface which is separate from the UI thread. I believe that this is NOT the case.

From the Android developer reference for SurfaceView: "One of the purposes of this class is to provide a surface in which a secondary thread can render into the screen."
The key word being *can*. You still have to spawn the separate thread yourself, the SurfaceView just makes it easier to draw to a canvas in a separate thread.

If you take LunarLander as an example, it has just two threads: the UI thread, and a manually-spawned 'LunarThread' in which the physics are updated and the canvas (via SurfaceHolder.lockCanvas()) is drawn to, as fast as possible, independent of the UI thread.